# LSI HBA cards - span a virtual drive across two RAID controllers

Tags: raid, controller, raid-controller, hba, virtual-disk

I am able to create a virtual drive on one of the RAID controllers, but that virtual drive is isolated to that RAID controller.

I setup four (4) eval RAID cards:  LSI MegaRAID SAS 9271-8iCC  +  CacheVault Accessory Kit

I am using them in a DataON Cluster-In-A-Box (CiB-9470 4U 70 bay, Dual Node). Currently, I have two (2) MegaRAID controllers in each CiB node.

Each CiB node can see all 70 disks via their respective RAID controllers. Lets call them RAID Controller 0 & RAID Controller 1.

```
            RAID Controller 0  (35 Disks)
                            Port 0  -  Slot 0 – Slot 17
                            Port 1  -  Slot 18 – 34
            RAID Controller 1  (35 Disks)
                            Port 0  -  Slot 35 – Slot 52
                            Port 1  -  Slot 53 – Slot 69
```

I can only create a virtual drive using the disks on a single RAID controller. I am unable to create a virtual drive that spans both RAID controllers to take advantage of all 70 disks; Ex, 70 disk RAID 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware RAID is managed at the controller level. You simply can't build a RAID volume using disks from different controllers. A controller can only see and manage disks to which it's actually connected.

You could use software RAID, depending on your O.S.; but there's just no way you can handle this at the controller level.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain there is no such solution in hardware. Depending on your operating system, there might be ways in software. ZFS or storage pools come to mind.